# Add Field To All Pages

Tags: theme-development, custom-field

I'm trying to add a custom field to the built in Page content type. I've found lots of tutorials on how to do this for a single page, but I want to do this for all pages in my theme.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that yourself, take a look at function [`add_meta_box`](http://look4wp.com/add_meta_box) (don't forget the examples). That page has almost everything you need to create a custom meta box for a certain post type.

If you want to simplify your work, you might want to use an utility like [Meta Box plugin](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/meta-box). This plugin can help you register your custom meta box with many built-in fields.